# Save space writing bitset to a file in C++

Tags: c++, iostream, bitset, compression, lossless-compression

I was wondering how I can save space writing a bitset to a file ( probably using iostream) in c++.  Will breaking up the bitset into bitset of size 8 and then writing each individual bitset to the file save me space?  What is your thought about this.  This is the intention of data compression.

Answer (score 0):

If you normally write one byte per bit in the bitset, then yes, storing eight elements to a byte will save you 7/8 of the space in the limit (you will have to store the size of the bitset somewhere, of course).

For example, this writes a `bitset` using one character per bit (7/8 overhead):

```
for (size_t i=0, n=bs.size(); i<n; ++i)
    stream << bs[i];
```

while this stores it optimally compact (if we disregard padding at the end):

```
for (size_t i=0, n=(bs.size() + 1) % 8; i<n; ++i) {
    uint8_t byte=0;
    for (size_t j=0; j<8; ++j)
        byte = (byte << 1) | bs[i*8 + j];
    stream << byte;
}
```

Note that `uint8_t` is not standard C++03. It resides in C99's `<stdint.h>` or C++0x's `<cstdint>`. You can also use an `std::bitset<8>` if you want.

Comment: I'm just not sure of the behaviour of the writing if I write a bitset of lets say size 600.

Comment: @Apoc: I don't understand what you're afraid of. Could you post some code?

Comment: @Apoc: You might want to use a `boost::dynamic_bitset` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) instead if your bitsets are very large and can have variable size.

Comment: Do you know if using an `ostream_iterator` will also use a byte per bit? What about using an `ostream_iterator` with `vector<bool>`?

Comment: @user470379: neither will write single bits, since an `ostream` simply won't allow that. C++ streams are fundamentally byte-oriented, as are modern operating systems, file systems, network devices, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `boost::dynamic_bitset` instead, you can specify the type of the underlying blocks and retrieve them with `to_block_range` and `from_block_range` functions.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#to_block_range

(for example, use `unsigned char` as block type and store them in a stream in binary mode)